# Como obter dinamicamente dia específico numa query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Gostaria de obter o ultimo dia do mes anterior de uma forma dinamica. Eu não sei como é que hei de por o `wo.createdtime <= Moth(current_date)` algo assim do genero e isto tá em milisegundos, complica ainda mais. Se alguem poder ajudar, agradecia.

```
SELECT wo.WORKORDERID AS "Request ID",   
  FROM WorkOrder wo   
WHERE > (((wo.CREATEDTIME >= 1527807600000)  
 AND ((wo.CREATEDTIME != 0) 
 AND (wo.CREATEDTIME IS NOT NULL))) 
 AND ((wo.CREATEDTIME <= 1530399599000) 
 AND (((wo.CREATEDTIME != 0)
 AND (wo.CREATEDTIME IS NOT NULL))   
 AND (wo.CREATEDTIME != -1))))   
 AND wo.ISPARENT='1'
 AND wo.IS_CATALOG_TEMPLATE='0'
```

Comment: é o último dia do mês anterior que tenha na sua tabela, ou do calendário ? se for da tabela, [edit] a pergunta e coloque a estrutura dela, e exemplo dos dados

Comment: é o ultimo dia do mes anterior do caledário , e o problema é que eu tenho esse resultado de uma forma fixa e não tou a conseguir por isto de uma forma dinamica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT (date_trunc
        ('month',  current_date - interval '1' month) 
        + 
        interval '1 month' - interval '1 day')::date
AS ultimo_dia_mes_anterior;
```

Hoje, a consulta retorna:

```
2018-06-30
```

Answer (score 0):

O PostgreSQL tem 2 métodos para manipular datas. Primeiro, com [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), voce trunca a data para ter o ano e o mês atual. Da documentacao:

> field selects to which precision to truncate the input value. The return value is of type timestamp or interval with all fields that are less significant than the selected one set to zero (or one, for day and month).

OU seja, você passa o campo que você quer truncar ('year', 'month,'hour', etc.) e ele retorna pra você uma data com os valores menos significantes zerados. Com isso você consegue ter o primeiro dia do mês atual.

Mas você quer o dia anterior ao primeiro dia do mes. Para isso, basta subtrair 1 dia da data truncada. Essa subtração você consegue fazer com o comando [interval](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), bastando passar o intervalo de 1 dia.

Fica então assim a consulta:

```
postgres=# select (date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '1 day');
    ?column?
------------------------
 2018-06-30 00:00:00-04
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ainda n experimentei mas ja tou a perceber a logica, eu como nunca mexi com postgres isto tem umas funções diferentes do que o sql normal.